# argparse: don't show usage on -h

Tags: python, argparse

The code

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
p = ArgumentParser(description = 'foo')
p.add_argument('-b', '--bar', help = 'a description')
p.parse_args()
```

...results in the output:

```
$ python argparsetest.py -h
usage: argparsetest.py [-h] [-b BAR]

foo

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -b BAR, --bar BAR  a description
```

What I'd like is:

```
$ python argparsetest.py -h
foo

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -b BAR, --bar BAR  a description
```

e.g., no usage message when asking for help. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

definitely possible -- but I'm not sure about documented ...

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser,SUPPRESS
p = ArgumentParser(description = 'foo',usage=SUPPRESS)
p.add_argument('-b', '--bar', help = 'a description')
p.parse_args()
```

---

From reading the source, I've hacked a little something together which seems to work when displaying error messages as well ... **warning** -- This stuff is *mostly* undocumented, and therefore liable to change at any time :-)

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser,SUPPRESS
import sys as _sys
from gettext import gettext as _

class MyParser(ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):    
        usage = self.usage
        self.usage = None
        self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
        self.exit(2, _('%s: error: %s\n') % (self.prog, message))
        self.usage = usage


p = MyParser(description = 'foo',usage=SUPPRESS)
p.add_argument('-b', '--bar', help = 'a description')
p.parse_args()
```

Comment: @DSM -- I can't find it in the docs either ... I got to it by reading the source ...

Comment: Unfortunately that also suppresses it on an error or empty command line, which I don't want. I only want to suppress it when -h or --help is passed on the command line.

Comment: @elhefe -- Updated.  This code works, but it relys on the argparse internals.  I think they're pretty stable at this point though ...

Comment: Looks good, although you don't need to save and restore self.usage as you're exiting the program.

Comment: @elhefe -- It's true -- but it's a little defensive.  After all, what if someone subclasses again and overrides `self.exit` to do something else?

Answer (score 7):

Note: to not show usage for a specific argument, use

```
parser.add_argument('--foo', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#help).

Comment: totally what i wanted.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One additional note: if you don't want help at all you can construct the parser with add_help=False

```
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument("arg")
    return parser.parse_known_args()

def main():
    args, remaining = parse_args()
    print(args)
    print(remaining)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


user@host % python3 /tmp/test.py  f
Namespace(arg='f')
[]
user@host % python3 /tmp/test.py  f -h
Namespace(arg='f')
['-h']
user@host % python3 /tmp/test.py  f -h --help
Namespace(arg='f')
['-h', '--help']
user@host %
```