# How to display a custom message instead of the default help message which Argparse generates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Consider the following sample code

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('action', help='Action to take')
parser.add_argument('-b','--bar', help='Description for bar argument')
parser.parse_args()
```

The output of calling it with a `--help` argument would probably be something like this:

```
positional arguments:

action   Action to take


optional arguments:

-h, --help show this help message and exit
-b  --bar  Description for bar argument
```

I dont want the above default help text that Argparse generates. I want a message that is entirely written by me

For example calling the file with `--help` argument should display the following help message:

```
Please go to http://some_website.com/help to understand more about our software
```

So how do I provide my custom message to Argparse?

Comment: I think the following link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591168/argparse-dont-show-usage-on-h.  You can suppress what you don't want to show and just keep the description.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806664/python-argparse-override-help-from-parent?rq=1

Comment: In the default setup, `-h/--help` calls `parser.print_help()` and exits.  `print_help` uses `parser.format_help`.  You can customize these.  From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#printing-help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906513/argparse-custom-help-from-text-file

Comment: Another option is to look at `sys.argv` before calling `parse_args`.  If you see `help` (in some form) print the message and exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `print_help()` method. So, I have created a class called `MyArguementParser` that overrides `ArgumentParser` just like so:

```
import argparse
import sys as _sys

class MyArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):

    def print_help(self, file=None):
        if file is None:
            file = _sys.stdout
        message = "Please go to http://some_website.com/help to understand more about our software"
        file.write(message+"\n")
```

Now, instead of called `ArgumentParser`, you will call `MyArgumentParser` like so:

```
parser = MyArgumentParser() #THIS IS THE ONLY CHANGE YOU NEED TO MAKE
# parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('action', help='Action to take')
parser.add_argument('-b','--bar', help='Description for bar argument')
parser.parse_args()
```

Now, when you run the script using `-h` or `--help` flag!

You can also override `print_usage()` the same way to show the same message when the user misuses any of the provided arguments.